# VS2019+WDK10, missing Spectre-mitigated MSVC library for 16.11, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, wdk

Some weird stuff here. I'm trying to build a KMDF sample driver with VS2019 16.11.5 and WDK 10.0.19041.685 (also called version 2004 Dec 2020 update).

First, I got compilation error saying that I need to download Spectre-mitigated MSVC library.

[image]

Well, I try it, but got a new problem. The VS2019(16.11.5) installer does not show MSVC Spectre-mitigated MSVC library version for **exact** 16.11. Looks like the latest one it provides is 16.10 ().

[image: VS2019 installer, missing -16.11 Spectre-version]

Download the 16.10 one and resume trying, still compilation error.

I peek into my `D:\VSIDE\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC` folder, and see two *versions* of MSVC libs listed, **14.29.30133** and **14.29.30037** . The later is the one with spectre libs(so it's 600MB+ larger).

[image: two MSVC lib folders]

[image: 14.29.30037 with spectre libs]

However, the KMDF build tool insists to find MSVC libs in the *newer* 14.29.30133 folder, so Spectre-mitigated libs still CANNOT be found.

I know I can manually copy the required files from 14.29.30037 to 14.29.30133 to make things go on. BUT is it the decent way to do so, or is it a Microsoft toolset bug?

I'd like to ask how other kernel driver developers solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Typical agile problem, use Help > Send Feedback to report it.  Meanwhile, edit the .vcxproj file and add `<Driver_SpectreMitigation>false</Driver_SpectreMitigation>` to keep moving ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, several days later, I find out two workarounds for this issue.

First, as [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) stated, disable the Spectre lib in .vcxproj. This can be configured from UI.

[image: UI disable Spectre lib]

Second, explicitly select a MSVC library version for current project. This can also be configured in project settings UI.

[image: UI select MSVC Toolset version]

### ==== 2022.02.11 UPDATE ====

Finally got it，the Spectre-lib with version number 14.29.30133 is called "(Latest)", so it is listed **above** the oldest version, and this defeats the novice. Use this and problem solved.

[image: Spectre lib v14.29-16.11 here]

Sure, it is stupid enough to mark it as merely "(Lastest)". He should have named it **MSVC v142 - VS2019 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (v14.29-16.11)(Latest)**" .